# Defining a variable inside IIFE block

Tags: javascript, iife

Can someone explain what is the difference between following two IIFE blocks:

```
a) (f1 = function(){console.log('IIFE Block1')})()
b) (var f1 = function(){console.log('IIFE Block2')})()
```

I understand that "b)" upon execution will throw error.
What is the use of defining the variable "f1" and what are its properties.

Comment: in a) `f1` will be the anonymous function `{console.log('IIFE Block1')}` - it's usefulness in that code is minimal

Comment: @JaromandaX no.

Comment: @vol7ron - I guess we'll have to disagree - but I'm right

Comment: @vol7ron sure it is

Comment: @vol7ron - https://jsfiddle.net/h2dyo6f8/ or ... read the answer below I guess :p

Comment: In strict mode, both will throw an exception. Not much difference. Neither are useful.

Comment: @JaromandaX no, the second won't even execute

Comment: @vol7ron - even the QUESTION states that, so why would you think I thought otherwise? seriously, get over it, you were "not strict"ly wrong :p

Comment: @JaromandaX you right, you right.

Comment: well, not strictly right - get it ... strict ... I crack myself up :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one doesn't use a declaration keyword, so `f1` will become global (which defeats the purpose of the IIFE). But, that is legal syntax for an expression - the function can be invoked and the result (if any) can be assigned to `f1`. Note that this won't work with `use strict` in effect.

```js
(f1 = function(){console.log('IIFE Block1')})()

// f1 is Global and can be accessed from anywhere
console.log(f1);
```

The second one fails because it's invalid IIFE syntax - it is a **declaration** and assignment statement, which is not an expression that can be evaluated.

```js
(var f1 = function(){console.log('IIFE Block2')})()
```

Comment: Thanks Scott for the explanation. I understand now regarding the valid syntax for an IIFE.

Answer (score 2):

`a` only works outside of strict mode. `f1` is being implicitly defined as a global variable and set to the value of your IIFE. If you try this in strict mode, an error will be thrown because `f1` hasn't been explicitly declared with `var`, `let`, `const`, or as a function argument:

```js
function quirks() {
  (f1 = function() { return 'f1 IIFE'; })();
  return f1;
}
console.log(quirks());

function strict() {
  "use strict";
  
  (f2 = function() { return 'f2 IIFE'; })();
  return f2;
}
console.log(strict());
```

Comment: you could of course declare `f1` earlier in the code if you wanted :p

Answer (score 1):

In addition to all the great answers, you'll realize that most of this is syntactic allowance.  You can apply the same methodology of the first one, which is operating on the `window` object, to any other defined object:

```js
(f1 = function(){console.log('IIFE Block1')})()
console.log(f1);

// managed object
var local = {};
(local.f2 = function(){console.log('IIFE Block2')})()
console.log(local.f2);


// or any predefined variable
var f3;
(f3 = function(){console.log('IIFE Block3')})()
console.log(f3);

// just not in the parens
// (var f4 = function(){console.log('IIFE Block4')})()
// console.log(f4);
```